# I how do for my methods make short in my class?

Tags: reactjs

I how do for my methods make short using functions that can receive the state and do changes? 
this with the purpose the that methods be most  clean.
also handle asicronic validations :(

```
onBlur(e){
  const field = e.target.name;
  const value = e.target.value;
  let errors = this.state.errors;
  let validFields = this.state.validFields;
  let invalid = this.state.invalid;


  if (edit && field === 'username' && edit.username === value) {
    return;
  }


  if (field === 'password2') {
    if (value !== this.state.password1){
      //console.log('password no conciden');
      errors[field] = 'password no conciden';
      validFields[field] = '';
      invalid = true;
    }else if (value === this.state.password1){
      validFields[field] = true;
      validFields['password1'] = true;
      errors[field] = "";
      invalid = false;

    }
    this.setState({validFields, errors, invalid});

    //return;
  }
  // Cheack field username
  this.props.ifExistsField("UsersModel", field, value).then((response) => {

    if(response.data[field] !== true){
      errors[field] = response.data[field];
      validFields[field] = '';
      invalid = true;

    } else {
      validFields[field] = response.data[field];
      errors[field] = "";
      invalid = false;


    }
    this.setState({validFields, errors, invalid});
  });

}
```

this is a form that be validator with method onBlur, but is very large.
thanks for help me!

Comment: edit is var control for if form be mode update.

Answer (score 0):

Component form.

```
onBlur(e){
  onBlurValidator(e, this);      
}
```

Function Validate, pass this as argument.

```
function onBlurValidator (e, form){
  const field = e.target.name;
  const value = e.target.value;
  let errors = form.state.errors;
  let validFields = form.state.validFields;
  let invalid = form.state.invalid;

  if (field === 'password2') {
    clean_password2(value, errors, validFields, invalid, form);
  }

  if (field === 'username') {
    clean_username(value, errors, validFields, invalid, form);
  }

}

function clean_password2(value, errors, validFields, invalid, form){
  // Cheack field username
  const password2 = "password2";
  const password1 = "password1";
  if (value !== form.state.password1){
    //console.log('password no conciden');
    errors[password2] = 'password no conciden';
    errors[password1] = 'password no conciden';
    validFields[password2] = '';
    invalid = true;
  }else if (value === form.state.password1){
    validFields[password2] = true;
    validFields[password1] = true;
    errors[password2] = "";
    errors[password1] = "";
    invalid = false;
  }
  form.setState({validFields, errors, invalid});

}

function clean_username (value, errors, validFields, invalid, form){
  // Cheack field username
  const username = "username";

  form.props.ifExistsField("UsersModel", username, value).then((response) => {

    if(response.data[username] !== true){
      errors[username] = response.data[username];
      validFields[username] = '';
      invalid = true;

    } else {
      validFields[username] = response.data[username];
      errors[username] = "";
      invalid = false;
    }
    form.setState({validFields, errors, invalid});
  });
}

export {onBlurValidator};
```

it looks better!